# Laravel 5.2 Data Update Not Working : Showing Error

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 PHP framework.When i try to update any data it's through an Error.I don't why is this happening? I have searched in google but i can not get any result which is solve my problem.

My **routes.php:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'jobs'], function () {
    Route::get('all', ['as' => 'allJobs' , 'uses' => 'JobController@index']);
    Route::get('create', ['as' => 'addNewJobs' , 'uses' => 'JobController@create']);
    Route::post('save', ['as' => 'saveJob' , 'uses' => 'JobController@store']);
    Route::get('edit/{id}', ['as' => 'editJobs' , 'uses' => 'JobController@edit']);
    Route::put('update', ['as' => 'updateJob' , 'uses' => 'JobController@update']);
    Route::get('delete/{id}', ['as' => 'deleteJob' , 'uses' => 'JobController@destroy']);

});
```

My **JobController.php:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id=0)
{
    $id = $request->input("id");        
    $job = Jobs::find($id);
    $job->jobTitle = $request->input('jobTitle');
    $job->jobCat = $request->input('jobCat');
    $job->jobSummary = $request->input('jobSummary');

    $job->save();        
    return redirect(route('allJobs'));
}
```

**Error:**

[image: Error Image]

I really don't know where is the problem? Could any one tell me the solution of it?

> **NOTE: I can give you more information if you need.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my problem.My problem with `jobs.blade.php`file.First time i did not pass any method and the `$job` variable also in the `Form`.Now i am added two `hidden` `input` field for getting `method` value and `id`s  value.If i replace the `blade` form with below code then it working good.

```
{!! Form::model($job,array('route' => 'updateJob', 'class' => 'form-horizontal',  'id'=> 'add-form', 'files' => true)) !!}
<input type='hidden' name='_method' value='put'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{!! $job->id !!}'>

//here is other all fields
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Thanks to all.Hope this will help for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

routes.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'jobs'], function () {
    Route::get('all', ['as' => 'allJobs' , 'uses' => 'JobController@index']);
    Route::get('create', ['as' => 'addNewJobs' , 'uses' => 'JobController@create']);
    Route::post('save', ['as' => 'saveJob' , 'uses' => 'JobController@store']);
    Route::get('edit/{id}', ['as' => 'editJobs' , 'uses' => 'JobController@edit']);
    Route::post('update', ['as' => 'updateJob' , 'uses' => 'JobController@update']);
    Route::get('delete/{id}', ['as' => 'deleteJob' , 'uses' => 'JobController@destroy']);

});
```

JobController.php: (Make sure to add `use Input;` after the `namespace` in your JobController.php)

```
public function update()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $id = $input["id"];        
    $job = Jobs::findOrFail($id);
    if( !isset($job->id) )  // check if job is found
       return redirect('to-some-404-route-if-not-found'); 
    $job->jobTitle = $input['jobTitle'];
    $job->jobCat = $input['jobCat'];
    $job->jobSummary = $input['jobSummary'];

    if( $job->save() ) 
       return redirect(route('allJobs'));
    # return something; add some flash message that indicates failure
}
```

Comment: I added `use Input` after the `namespace` and its show Input class not found.This is only one error now.Appreciate your help.

Comment: To fix that error you need to add this line `'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class` to the `aliases` in your app.php. And make sure to run composer dump-autoload after that.

Answer (score 0):

your accessing the route "jobs/update" via GET. change the http method to PUT, maybe in your form or in your ajax request

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your update route as

```
Route::put('update', ['as' => 'updateJob' , 'uses' => 'JobController@update']);
```

replace this line with

```
Route::put('update/{id}', ['as' => 'updateJob' , 'uses' => 'JobController@update']);
```

then you have to add in your form

```
method_field('PUT');
```

Comment: I have tried with `{!! method_field('PUT') !!}` then its shows error `Creating default object from empty value`.

Comment: can you please show view part.

    Route::put('update/{id}', ['as' => 'updateJob' , 'uses' => 'JobController@update']);
I think you miss id in route

Comment: http://prntscr.com/add9il this is view part when i click update its shows that error.

Comment: I declared `Route::get('edit/{id}', ['as' => 'editJobs' , 'uses' => 'JobController@edit']);` so its edited al right but its do not save the updated info into database.

Comment: after adding `update/{id}` i can not edit anything its shows: http://prntscr.com/addc21 and my `edit.blade.php` declared form is ` {!! Form::model($job,array('route' => 'updateJob', 'class' => 'form-horizontal','id'=> 'export-form', 'files' => true))!!}`

Comment: Pass job Id in form model --- {!! Form::model($job,array('route' => 'updateJob', 'class' => 'form-horizontal','id'=> 'export-form', 'files' => true , $job->id) )!!}

Answer (score 0):

> after adding update/{id} i can not edit anything its shows: prntscr.com/addc21 and my edit.blade.php declared form is ` {!! Form::model($job,array('route' => 'updateJob', 'class' => 'form-horizontal','id'=> 'export-form', 'files' => true))!!}

as from your comment, you're getting the exception as you pasted here - http://prntscr.com/addc21 because in your edit.blade.php file you have array('route' => 'updateJob' ...) and because you've changed the route to update/{id} now you need to pass that id
so simply replace
**

> route' => 'updateJob'

with

> 'route' => ['updateJob',$jobId]

and for this issue - http://prntscr.com/addf7s can you please provide what is on line 90 in JobController. I just assume that you're imported wrong Request class.